# How do I fix an ntfs filesystem on a RAID5 volume?

Tags: ntfs, chkdsk, raid-5

I have a RAID5 volume with an ntfs filesystem of which chkdsk keeps telling me there are 5 unindexed files. I can't take the volume offline during the workday, so I run chkdsk /f on it, and then say yes to running chkdsk on reboot. I then schedule a reboot for sometime at night. The next day I run chkdsk without /f and again get 5 unindexed files and the message that I should run chkdsk with /f to fix the filesystem. What should I do to fix it? Should I run chkdsk /r or is there no point in doing so (or worse, can it do further damage to the filesystem) since it's a RAID5 volume?

I'm running windows server 2003.

Comment: How have you created the RAID array? BIOS "fakeRAID" or a dedicated RAID card? Might seem an odd question but fakeRAID can often be not so great (compared to a dedicated card) and might be giving your the problem

Comment: Dedicated RAID card

Comment: A night-time task but: Have you tried booting to the recovery console (F8) to run the chkdsk? What does Event Viewer say the files are? Any other logs?

Comment: I haven't tried booting to the recovery console. Event viewer doesn't say anything.